# I need to validate two uitextfields differently. How do I do this?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

One text field only takes alphabet characters and the other one is alphanumeric.  I have defined shouldChangeCharactersInRange in my ViewController for one of them.  Now I don't know where I'm supposed to define the logic for other uitextfield.

Can someone help me understand how this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options. If you have created iVars for your text fields, checking which one is calling `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is as simple as `==`. Below I've also shown that another option would be to assign tags to the text fields and check the tag of the sending text field.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //Your first option
    if (textField == myFirstTextField) {
        //
    }else{
        //
    }
    //another option, if you don't want to create iVars you can assign tags to your text fields and do this
    if (textField.tag == 99) {
        //
    }else{
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If they both have the same delegate, then they would both be validated in the same shouldChangeCharactersInRange method. You need to put an if-else clause in that method to check which text field is the sender. You need IBOutlets for the two text fields so you can do the comparison.